# Javascript : this.getAttribute("href") not working

Tags: javascript

I using javascript in js file like this:

```
document.body.onclick = function(ev) {
    alert(this.getAttribute("href"));
};
```

but that code gave me `null`.

I don't want using `jQuery`. for example `$(this).attr('href');`

Do you got any better suggest? I want get last `href` when user click on any `<a>` tags.

Comment: The `<body>` tag doesn't have an `href` attribute.

Comment: add HTML for full scope

Comment: Did you mean `ev.target` instead of `this`? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and use `console.log(this);` to figure out what `this` actually points to. Also use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: @Xufox thanks, `ev.target` worked. which is different `addEventListener` with `document.body.onclick` ??

Comment: @Xufox Can you answer this question via `addEventListener` please. because my `javascript` is weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re trying to do is called [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/4642212), however, you’re trying to access the clicked element via `this`. This might work in jQuery, but in regular JavaScript events (e.g. by binding to the `onclick` property or by using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) `this` refers to the object you’re binding the event to, i.e. in code like this, `this` always refers to `<body>`:

```js
document.body.onclick = function(ev) {
  console.log("onclick variant — `this` is", this);
};

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  console.log("addEventListener variant — `this` is", this);
});
```

```html
<div>Click me to see what <code>this</code> refers to.</div>
```

To see which element actually has been clicked, in a nutshell, you need `ev.target`:

```js
document.body.onclick = function(ev) {
  console.log("onclick variant — `ev.target` is", ev.target);
};

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  console.log("addEventListener variant — `ev.target` is", ev.target);
});
```

```html
<div>Click me to see what <code>this</code> refers to.</div>
```

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), since this is more modern and allows binding more than one event listener and provide more control over event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanted to write something like this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert(this.href);
    });
}
```

**Note:**
`this.getAttribute('href');` works as well, but –as stated in the comments– you were selecting one item, `document.body`, which has no `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You code worked, but body have not href attribute.
But use like this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a")
var onClick = function (event) {
    alert(event.target.getAttribute("href"));
}
elems.forEach((el) =>{
    el.addEventListener("click", onClick);
});
```

Comment: When binding event listeners to every single element, you don’t need `event.target` anymore and can directly access `this`, but this approach doesn’t utilize event delegation.

Comment: if you wanna checking bubling event in while cycle, it is not best idea